# Android Resources Compilation Failed

Tags: android, compilation

I have Compilation Error as below

```
here`Android resource compilation failed
Output:  D:\RukhiVivah5\app\src\main\res\mipmap- 
xxxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file 
does not start with PNG signature.

Command: C:\Users\MAHESH\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2- 
3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\01d7b921fe2508ed1a0270e1a2e350cc\aapt2-3.2.1- 
4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
    -o \
D:\RukhiVivah5\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release \
D:\RukhiVivah5\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1
```

I am trying to Change Icon from AndroidManifest.xml and my AndroidManifest.xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mahesh.rukhivivah"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/rlvg"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/rlvg"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity android:name=".Location"/>
<activity android:name=".MumbaiMale" />
<activity android:name=".MumbaiFemale" />
<activity android:name=".GujaratMale" />
<activity android:name=".GujaratFemale"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Try if anyone had same problem while changing Icon in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: most probably your images have wrong extension. Check your images if they are JPEG with .png extension

Comment: Umair I have Checked it is png Images converted from jpeg. It's  ic_launcher_png Error

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons of this problem

1. you have change image extension like image is jpeg and you have changed it to png.
2. you have converted image using online tools and it only change its extension instead of proper format.
3. try to add

   > aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }

delete cache folders and file and rebuild your project hope it will works.

Comment: Shoaib Akram, I am new to android hence kindly inform me where to add "aaptOptions {cruncherEnabled=false}

Comment: aaptOption not available in buil.gradle